# Complex-valued integrals on Lie groups

Tags: integration, representation-theory, lie-groups, characters

I've been learning about some representation theory of compact Lie groups, and one of the $G$-averaging tricks has thrown me for a bit of a loop. Given a finite group $G$, I'm familiar with the trick of summing over the group to obtain a Hermitian inner product on the class functions: $$\langle \phi, \psi\rangle := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \phi(g)\overline{\psi(g)}$$
I'm trying to understand how to boost this idea to the compact Lie group setting. Let $|dg|$ be a Haar measure on a compact Lie group $G$. It makes sense that $$\langle \phi,\psi\rangle:= \frac{1}{\text{vol}(G)} \int_G \phi(g)\overline{\psi(g)} \ |dg|$$
is the desired generalization, since restricting to the case $\dim G=0$ recovers the above summation. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to make sense of the integral. The way I learned how to integrate on (compact) Lie groups is via densities: one simply pulls a density back to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via a coordinate chart and integrates it there (using the usual un-oriented integral). But the integrand here is complex-valued. Am I meant to interpret this integral by splitting the integrand into real and imaginary parts and integrating each separately? Or is there some sort of notion of a "complex density bundle" that I need to use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you think of $G$ as a measurable space with Haar measure $dg$, then it's as you said: a complex valued integral over $G$ is defined to be the sum of the integrals over the real and imaginary parts.  See e.g. the beginning of big Rudin.  But this is seldom how the integral is actually calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the integral of a complex-value function is just given by integrating its real and imaginary parts separately.  This is not special to Lie groups in any way, and is a standard convention whenever one speaks of any sort of integral in any context. (For instance, surely you have also seen integrals of complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$!)

In your case, you could also define it using a "complex density bundle", which would be nothing but the complexification of the ordinary real density bundle.  This isn't anything fancy, though: as a real bundle, it's just a direct sum of two copies of the real density bundle (one for the real part and one for the imaginary part), and then when you pull back to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and integrate, you are again just integrating the real and imaginary parts separately.